# Using JOOQ just to store table/column names and types with no regard to Record types

Tags: java, jooq

I'm currently evaluating `JOOQ` because I believe I started reinventing the wheel which looks very close to part of `JOOQ` :)

Now, while digging in great `JOOQ` documentation I've found that my use case lies somewhere between [Using JOOQ as SQL Builder](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder/) and [Using JOOQ as SQL Builder with Code generation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-builder-with-code-generation/) i.e. I would like to:

1. Create plain SQL strings like it is shown in [Using JOOQ as SQL Builder](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-standalone-sql-builder/) part
2. Instead of using hard-coded `DSL.fieldByName("BOOK","TITLE")` constructs, I prefer storing name of a table along with it's column names and types like it's shown in [Using JOOQ as SQL Builder with Code generation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/getting-started/use-cases/jooq-as-a-sql-builder-with-code-generation/) part
3. I prefer not to use code generation (at least not on regular basis), but rather creating `TableImpl` myself when new table is needed.

While digging in manual, I've found how table implementation should look like in chapter [Generated tables](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/code-generation/codegen-tables/). However, [TableImpl](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/TableImpl.html) class as well as [Table](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html) interface should be parameterized with record type and the same goes for [TableField](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableField.html) class. I believe this is done for easier type inference when directly querying database and retrieving results, though I may be mistaken.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a guide in manual on how to create [Table](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html) and [TableField](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableField.html) implementations? Or I can simply generate them once for my database schema and use generated code as a guideline?
2. How can I gracefully "discard" record type parameters in implemented classes? First, I thought about using `java.lang.Void` class as type parameter but then I noticed that only subclasses of [Record](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html) are allowed... The reason is that I don't need record types at all because I plan to use generated by `JOOQ` SQL queries in something like [Spring JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) so mapping is done by myself.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Before I answer: Why would you want to avoid code generation, when in the end, you would like to use artefacts similar to the ones generated by jOOQ's code generator?

Comment: It's more like matter of taste :) Usually after code generation I anyway review all generated code just to be sure everything went well and to know what was generated and where, so very often I feel that coding it myself gives me more control of what is happening and gives me more understanding of framework I'm using. But as I said it's more like personal preference than rational argument :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your use-case, I'm not sure why you'd like to roll your own `Table` and `TableField` implementations rather than using the ones generated by jOOQ. As you stated yourself, you don't *have* to regenerate that code every time the DB schema changes. Many users will just generate the schema once in a while and then put the generated artefacts under version control. This will help you keep track of newly added changes.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, there are some examples around the use of [`CustomTable`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/). You may also find some people [sharing similar experiences](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/7kyy0oU5I_A/tQ7WDRKNfoYJ) on the [user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/zP0ITqWhB7Y/a5-sibi8NfcJ)
2. Yes you can just use `Record`. Your minimal custom table type would then be:

   ```
   class X extends TableImpl<Record> {
       public X() {
           super("x");
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that you will be using jOOQ's *internal* API (`TableImpl`), which is not officially supported. While I'm positive that it'll work, it might break in the future, e.g. as the super constructor signature might change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response - it clarified a lot! After looking at how `CustomTable` and `CustomField` should be implemented I found out that yeah, I will probably use code generation :) In future though I plan to transfer database schema creation scripts to `Java / JOOQ` (if it is supported, otherwise will have to write my own), because IMO that is more typesafe. So at that point I may need to create `Table` / `Field` instances myself.